# How does one solve for a generalized quadratic in multiple dimensions as in $a w^Tw + b^T w + c = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, optimization, numerical-methods, quadratic-forms

Consider:

$$a w^Tw + b^T w + c = 0 $$

I would like to find a vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^D$ that satisfies the above equation. I realize that I need to choose D numbers to satisfy 1 equation, so my intuition (from linear algebra) tells me that there might be an infinite set of solutions for this (1 equation D unknowns). Thus, I thought that maybe additional constraints are needed. I am honestly not too worried about which one to choose as long as it satisfies the equation. However, if I really had to choose a criterion to choose a $w$ I would first require it to be real vector and perhaps choose $w$ closest to some other fixed (aprior chosen) $x$ (say for simplicity closest to the origin $x=0$). So the additional constraint is:

$$ min_w \| w - x\|^2 $$

or even

$$ \| w - x\|^2 = 0 $$

another constraint could be (normalized vector) is also good:

$$  \| w \|^2 = 1 $$

I mostly care to satisfy the "generalized quadratic", the additional constraint is there just incase its needed (no complex number solutions).

Also Ideally I'd like to implement the solution in a maths program, for example, python or matlab.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli you sure thats right? That only seems to hold when $c = 0$. Remember that the most important thing to satisfy in this question is the equation, not the constraint. The constraint is there just to help us pick some solution from the set of valid solution. I just suggested one criteria to choose, but any (computable) criteria should be fine.

Comment: Since you changed the request to $\lVert w\rVert=1$, I deleted the previous comment. As I said, though, $\lVert w\rVert^2=0$ was not a good costraint because, for *any vector* $x$, $\lVert x\rVert^2=0$ *if and only if* $x=0$. Of course it was right. What you said is just that $w=0$ is a solution of the problem if and only if $c=0$. Remember that conditions imposed on an object do not have priority ("computable" or not), and if your condtion is "$w$ is exactly this very special vector", then the problem reduces to "is this very special vector a solution?". Which may not be the case.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli My apologies if Im being very dense, but if $c \neq 0$ how is $w = 0$ a solution? Just to clarify, its more important to satisfy the equation than worrying about the constraint. The constraint is just an additional condition just in case one need to choose some element from the possible solution.

Answer (score 4):

Multiply through by $4a$ (a scalar assumed nonzero) to get $$
\begin{align}
(2aw)^T(2aw)+2b^T(2aw)+4ac
&=0\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that $b^Tw$ is real, so it is equal to its transpose, $w^Tb$. So you can complete the square:
$$
\begin{align}
(2aw+b)^T(2aw+b)
&=b^Tb-4ac\\
\left\lVert 2aw+b\right\rVert^2
&=\lVert b\rVert^2-4ac\\
\left\lVert w+\frac{b}{2a}\right\rVert^2
&=\frac{\lVert b\rVert^2-4ac}{4a^2}\\
\left\lVert w+\frac{b}{2a}\right\rVert
&=\sqrt{\frac{\lVert b\rVert^2-4ac}{4a^2}}
\end{align}
$$

So the solution set is a sphere of radius $\sqrt{\frac{\lVert b\rVert^2-4ac}{4a^2}}$ centered at $-\frac{b}{2a}$. Of course this solution set is empty if $\lVert b\rVert^2-4c$ is negative. Note that over $\mathbb{R}^1$, this is exactly the quadratic formula, since a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^1$ with positive radius is precisely two points.

---

You ask for additional constraints to pin down one vector in particular on this sphere. Hopefully it is clear that the "$\lVert w\rVert=1$" idea won't pan out in general. Generally you could look to your other suggestion that you minimize the norm of $w$, but that won't give a unique vector if $b=0$.

Instead, you can parametrize the sphere. The solution set is a $D-1$ dimensional sphere, and you can use [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Stereographic_projection) from $\mathbb{R}^{D-1}\cup\{\text{one point}\}$ to $S^{D-1}$ to parametrize a unit sphere, then scale to radius $\sqrt{\frac{\lVert b\rVert^2-4ac}{4a^2}}$ and shift to center $-\frac{b}{2a}$. This will give you a parametrization of all solutions to your equation.

Answer (score 2):

If $a=0$, let $w=\frac{-cb}{\left\|b\right\|^2}$

WLOG, assume that $a>0$

Let's try to complete the square,
Note that your equality is just
$$\left(\sqrt{a}w+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}b\right)^T\left(\sqrt{a}w+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}b\right)+c-\frac{b^Tb}{4a}=0$$

$$\left\|\sqrt{a}w+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}b\right\|^2=\frac{b^Tb}{4a}-c$$

Now, if the RHS is nonnegative, you can choose $$\sqrt{a}w+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}b=v$$

where $v$ satisfies $$\left\|v\right\|^2=\frac{b^Tb}{4a}-c$$

and solve for $w$.

For instance, you can choose $v=\left(\sqrt{\frac{b^Tb}{4a}-c}\right)e_i$ and $$w=-\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{v}{\sqrt{a}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us take $D=2$. Denoting by $x$ and $y$ the components of $w$, and by $u$ and $v$ those of $b$, your question can be re-phrased into "find points on the curve with equation"

$$a(x^2+y^2)+ux+vy+c=0$$

Assuming $a \neq 0$ (see Remark 2), an equivalent form is :

$$x^2+y^2+2u'x+2v'y+c'=0 \ \ (1) \ \text{with} \ u'=u/(2a), v'=v/(2a), c'=c/a$$

or

$$(x-u')^2+(y-v')^2=p \ \ \text{with} \ \ p:=u'^2+v'^2-c'$$

($p$ is called the "power") which may describe either the set of points constituting a circle, or a point or the void set, according to the fact that the RHS can be considered as the square of a radius or not.

Conclusion:

if $p>0$ ; it is a circle ; an infinite number of solutions.

if $p=0$ : a single point ; a single solution $(u',v')$.

if $p<0$ : no solution.

Remark 1 : the particular case $D=2$ is illustrative of the general case, with (hyper)spheres instead of circles. Working with $D=3$ might be a good idea to get an idea of the generalization.

Remark 2 : In the case $a=0$, the equation is that of an hyperplane : one has always an infinite number of solutions.

Remark 3 : the sign of $p$ is clearly the sign of $D=u^2+v^2-4ac$. The fact that this expression looks like a discriminant is not mere chance. It is linked to a way to write the initial condition under a certain matrix form

Let $A=aI_n$:

$$a w^Tw + b^T w + c = w^T\begin{pmatrix}A&b\\b^T&c\end{pmatrix}w$$

and the use of Schur's determinant formula.